# How might the absence of faith-based miracles in a magical world affect people's respect for religion?

Tags: magic, culture, religion

The magic of the world I'm thinking of has a wide range of effects, has existed since before humanity, and can be learned by basically anyone. This means that 'miracles', which are commonly used by real-life religions to sway unbelievers or impress followers, can be dismissed here as normal magical works. Many great feats like raising the dead or causing storms can be performed by exceptional wizards.

I am wondering how this mundaneness can affect religion, specifically how a lack of real miracles might curb its spread or the respect for it.

Comment: Sure some wizards are stronger than others and can do things that other can't. Magic will become an integral part of religion.

Comment: Welcome to the site, NightKing. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. To that end, questions need to be well-defined and well-constrained so an objectively "best" answer can be determined. The question, "Magic exists; how does it affect society" is impossibly broad to answer in the StackExchange format. There are simply too many ways for magic to work, cultures to spring up around it, and people to regard it.

Comment: As such, I am voting to put this question on hold as _primarily opinion-based_ until an [edit] is made to bring it into the site's scope. In the meantime, feel free to take the [tour] and check out our [site culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/6986) to get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: The question must be reformulated, because as it is right now it asks about a solution to a non-existent problem. I don't know of *any* religion, extant or historical, which uses or was using miracles in order *"to sway unbelievers or impress followers"*. Consider Christianism, for example. Christian priests do not perform visible miracles. In fact, no large-scale miracle is supposed to have happened since a very long time ago. What Christianism offers is a world-view, a set of values, and the hope in eternal life. Same for Mohammedanism, Buddhism, Zoroastrism, etc.

Comment: @AlexP Christianity is not employing the _display_ of miracles to sway non-believers, but _stories_ of miracles are important part of religion.

Comment: @Alexander: The actual mythology, the *stories*, is a different question. The question asks how organized religion would work in a world full of wizards, not about the mythologies of a world full of wizards. And anyway, both classical and Christian mythologies have stories which contain miracle-performing wizards who are not divine characters; think of Circe in classical mythology, or the Egyptian priests in the Abrahamic mythology. Actually, the Bible contains several stories where the point is that Yhwh can perform *greater* miracles than other gods/wizards.

Comment: So far as anyone knew at the time Earth's religions were created, magic was definitely a thing. That made religions MORE believable, not less. Nowadays, it's *disbelief* in magic that is causing religions to be dismissed as myths and storytales.

Comment: @AlexP "Actually, the Bible contains several stories where..." I think you already have the answer here.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  Please take a moment to [learn more about our culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) and take our [tour]. Please read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). The problems with quetions like this are they are not objective and tend to be very broad. Understand that [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107#92110).

Comment: @AlexP We see miracles performed almost everyday, whether they are some form of ambiguous healing or bizarrely weak magic. Granted, the scientific evidence for their effectiveness is practically zero, but we still see millions get impressed by them.

Comment: @NightKing: That's why in order to avoid such discussions I said *large-scale* miracle. Small-scale miracles are mundane.

Comment: @AlexP It doesn't really matter if their scale isn't that big; most people don't need to see a sea parting in order to convert. A simple effect does the trick for most people, and that is all that religion needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that one of 3 scenarios happen

1. The new religions, some will worship the god that gave them the gift of magic and claim that we must be worthy or give thanks for it."very simple"
2. Religions will act the same way that they do now. Just because there is magic does not prove that there is no god or punishment for sins. Perhaps they could claim that some actions or magic are unholy and that there god will punish them for it or they could just be like the ones we have now.
3. Religious groups take magic items that lets them perform very difficult works of magic "think the philosopher's stone in fullmetal alchemist" and will use them either openly or hidden and claim that they have miracles from god when in reality it's the magic items

sorry for my bad english